# How do I get a numerical value for all the characters that are repeated in a certain string?

Tags: ruby, loops, methods

```
def num_repeats(string)
    letters = string.chars
    idx = 0
    n = 1
    arr = []
    lettercount = 0
    while idx < letters.length
      lettercount = 0
      while n < letters.length
            if letters[idx] == letters[n]
                lettercount = 1
            end
            n+=1
        end
        if lettercount > 0
          arr.push(idx)
        end
        idx += 1
    end
    return arr.length
end

puts(num_repeats("abdbccc"))
# == 2 since 2 letters are repeated across the string of characters
```

I keep getting zero, although as i see it if a number is repeated the value of numbercount should shift from zero to one and then allow some value to get pushed into the array where I later get the length of said array to determine the number of repeated characters. Is there an issue with my loops?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Maybe post some expected inputs/outputs?

Comment: I hope this comment clarifies a bit

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

If you really want to use the same kind of code and algorithm to do that, then here are the problems of it :

In your second `while` loop the variable `n` is supposed to start from `idx+1`, considering you are trying to pick up an index and then find whether the character at that index is repeated somewhere after the index.

But even if you fix that you will get `3` for `abdbccc`. That kinda shows that your algorithm is wrong. When there are more than 2 occurrences of a repeated character, just like the process I said in the above para, you do that for every such character except for the last one, without checking whether the character had already been detected for repetition. Illustration :

```
str = 'aaa'
When idx = 0, you get str[idx] == str[n=1], adds it to the result.
When idx = 1, you get str[idx] == str[n=2], adds it to the result.
```

Now you counted `a` twice for repetition. I think you can fix that alone.

---

I think you are just trying to do the same as this (assumes you need to check lower case letters only) :

```
str = "abdbccc"
('a'..'z').count { |x| str.count(x) > 1 }
# => 2
```

Or if you need to check the number of repeated characters for any character :

```
str = "12233aabc"
str.chars.group_by(&:to_s).count do |k, v|
  v.size > 1
end
# => 3
```

It's Ruby we are talking about. It's not really a good idea to write code like that in Ruby, I mean you are using a lot of `while` loops and manually tracking down their counters, while in Ruby you usually do not have to deal with those, considering all the convenient, less error-prone and shorter alternatives Ruby provides. I think you have a C like background, I recommend that you learn more of Ruby and Ruby way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understood what you were trying to do, maybe you could use a hash to assist:

```
def num_repeats(string)
    letters = string.chars
    counter_hash = Hash.new(0)
    letters.each { |l| counter_hash[l] += 1 }
    counter_hash
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this inner loop

```
  while n < letters.length
        if letters[idx] == letters[n]
            lettercount = 1
        end
        n+=1
```

But nowhere are you resetting `n`, so after this loop has scanned once, it will skip past every subsequent time

You can mostly fix that by setting `n` to `idx + 1` here

```
while idx < letters.length
  lettercount = 0
  n = idx + 1
  while n < letters.length
```

You still will get a result of `3` because you are not detecting that `c` has already been counted

You can fix this final problem with a couple more tweaks

```
def num_repeats(string)
    letters = string.chars
    idx = 0
    arr = []
    lettercount = 0
    while idx < letters.length
      lettercount = 0
      n = idx + 1                   # <== start looking after idx char
      while n < letters.length
            if letters[idx] == letters[n]
                lettercount += 1    # <== incrementing here
            end
            n+=1
        end
        if lettercount == 1         # <== check for exactly one
          arr.push(idx)
        end
        idx += 1
    end
    return arr.length
end
```

This works because now `lettercount == 2` for the first `c` so the duplicate is not counted until you get to the second `c` where `lettercount == 1`

This is still considered a poor solution as it has O(n**2) complexity. There are solutions - for example using `Hash` which are O(n)